# why mixitup pluggin isn't working?

Tags: html, css, mixitup

Thanks for sharing your time with me. Mixitup Pluggin isn't working in my HTML website. I use mixitup in the "portfolio-area" div. Can anyone please help me?

My site link:

http://shaylakarzon.kissr.com/mix/index.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$document.ready(function(){
    $('.mixitup-list').mixItUp();
});
```

This is wrong, change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mixitup-list').mixItUp();
});
```

Also - you have 2 jQuery scripts in your code (leave first and delete second script)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It works. But there are some errors may be. Can you please help me more?

Comment: I also see on your site that you load jQuery twice and some bootstrap JS components after you loaded Bootstrap. This is not good. You should load jQuery first, then Bootstrap and then other plugins and at the end your scripts.